# How to check if a role exists in a server?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a setup command for my discord bot. Part of the setup command is that it has to create a role. How do I make it so that if the role I want to create already exists in the server, the bot responds back saying the role already exists?

I would get the code I've done but it's only two IF statements and that wouldn't help.
Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to check the role? By name or by ID?

Answer (score 4):

You can loop through the roles of the server and check if the name matches.

```
let roleName = 'Your role name here';
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === roleName);
if (typeof role === undefined) {
    // Role doesn't exist, safe to create
} else {
    // Role exists
}
```

Beware though, this works on the *name* of the role, and Discord allows multiple roles with the same name.

Comment: Remember, it's now `message.guild.roles.cache.find`.